# Double and Float size

Tags: types, double, programming-languages

Is there any language in which a type named double occupies less space than the type name float?

Comment: Seems like a really random question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it. The name `double` refers to the precision. It means that it has twice the precision as a float. Storing more precision requires more space.